# How to put wait using aws cli for spot request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am launching AWS spot instance request using following CLI commands.

```sh
aws configure set aws_access_key_id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key wrrhiuhruiiwheuigxxxr
aws ec2 request-spot-instances \
  --instance-count 1 \
  --launch-specification file://specification.json 
aws ec2 wait spot-instance-request-fulfilled \
  --filters Name=launched-availability-zone,Values=us-east-1b
```

specification file

```json
{
    "ImageId": "ami-06dae4bf922346785",
    "KeyName": "fpga_instance_key",
    "SecurityGroupIds": [
        "sg-xxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "InstanceType": "f1.2xlarge",
    "Placement": {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b"
    },
    "IamInstanceProfile": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:instance-profile/aws-ec-role1"
    }
}
```

I wanted to put wait until instance request got fulfilled but even after request fulfilled , it keeps waiting. Is there any better way if I can wait using instance-id which have been assigned while creating request?
I have not any expertise in aws cli, I just use it for academic purpose and what all I got to know is through internet.

Comment: How does `Name` end up `launched-availability-zone`?

Comment: @jordanm, is it wrong ? I picked example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/spot-instance-request-fulfilled.html

what I understood that "launched-availability-zone" is name of filter and it's value is "us-east-1b"

Comment: Can you show your specification.json. does it include a subnet-id that's in us-east-1b?

Comment: @jordanm, sure , updated in problem

Comment: @jordanm
how to setup/get subnet id ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with waiting on the specific spot request id?

```sh
SPOT_REQUEST_ID=$(aws ec2 request-spot-instances \
  --instance-count 1 \
  --launch-specification file://specification.json \
  --query 'SpotInstanceRequests[].SpotInstanceRequestId' \
  --output text)

aws ec2 wait spot-instance-request-fulfilled \
  --filters Name=spot-instance-request-id,Values=$SPOT_REQUEST_ID
```